# erlang how to print unicode strings?

Tags: unicode, erlang

I use io:format to log messages to disk. Each message looks like [{field1, Content1}, {field2, Content2}, ...].

When I use io:format("~p", [Msg]) to print it, the file will look like [{field1, <<123,456,789,...>>}, ...].

But I want to print the unicode strings in their original form, not like integer arrays. What should I do?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

butter71 is right that you won't be able to just print out the term and have the binaries interpreted as Unicode. You will have to isolate the binaries first. When printing the binaries, you'll also need to use 't' which will allow you to print characters outside the latin1 range. See: http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/io_lib.html#format-2

Here is an example of printing out something like you have. I use unicode:characters_to_binary to convert what I input to UTF8. Just doing <<"¿,©,ō">> will cause an exception.

```
Msg = [{field1, unicode:characters_to_binary("¿,©,ō")}, {field2, ...}, ...]
[{field1, Field1}|_] = Msg.
io:format("~ts~n", [Field1]).
¿,©,ō
ok
io:format("~s~n", [Field1]). 
Â¿,Â©,Å
ok
```

As you can see the example without 't' produces garbled text.

If you're going to try and walk through your structure to convert it to a string and print it out, look at iolists.

Answer (score 1):

You might have success with just using "~s" instead of "~p".

Also check out the unicode module to do conversions --
http://erldocs.com/R14B/stdlib/unicode.html

edit: i read your question again and realize that you want to print the entire structure.  you will probably have to break it apart first, i don't think ~p will do what you want.